# How to use sql Like Operator in elastic search jdbc importer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

Technologies used in my project(Spring mvc , elasticsearch, rest api) , the problem is, my elastic search jdbc importer not able to run sql like operator, iam fetching null data , so please could anyone help me on this.

### Controller

```
package com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import org.springframework.http.MediaType; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.api.elasticsearch.repository.AutocompleteRepository; import com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.controller.BaseController; import com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.rest.entity.ResponseEntity; import com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.rest.util.RestStatus; import com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.util.ControllerUriConstant;

@RestController @RequestMapping(value = ControllerUriConstant.rest_autocomplete) public class RestAutocompleteController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired  AutocompleteRepository autoCompleteRepository;

    /**      *       * @param autoComplete   * @return   */     @RequestMapping(value = ControllerUriConstant.rest_autocompletesearch, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    public ResponseEntity getOverLayWords(@RequestParam("q") String name) {         System.out.println("check search value" + " " + name);      return getResponseEntity(autoCompleteRepository.findByName(name), RestStatus.OK.getCode(), RestStatus.OK.getText());    } }
```

### Repository

```
package com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.api.elasticsearch.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

import com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.api.elasticsearch.entities.Autocomplete;

public interface AutocompleteRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Autocomplete, String>{

    public List<Autocomplete> findByName(String name); }
```

### AutoComplete.bat

```
 @echo off

set DIR=%~dp0 set LIB=%DIR%..\lib\* set BIN=%DIR%..\bin

REM ??? echo {^
    "type" : "jdbc",^
    "jdbc" : {^
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ulearn_app",^
        "user" : "root",^
        "password" : "root",^
        "sql" :  "Select id as _id, id, name from course where name like '%name%'",^
        "treat_binary_as_string" : true,^
        "elasticsearch" : {^    
             "cluster" : "elasticsearch",^
             "host" : "localhost",^
             "port" : 9300^
        },^
        "index" : "ind_autocomplete"^
      }^ }^ | "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "%LIB%" -Dlog4j.configurationFile="%BIN%\log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
```

Comment: Please format your code...

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to do this.  I use the 2nd because I do not have to do the ' to \' change to use in jdbc and change \' to ' to test the query in sql tools.

1. Use `\' for each '`
2. OR.. Store the query in the database as a view.  And then call the view instead of the sql with the \'

   - In your database:

     `CREATE VIEW your_jdbc_view AS
     Select id as _id, id, name from course where name like '%name%';`
   - Change the line in your elasticsearch file to:

     "sql" :  `"Select * from your_jdbc_view",`